# Flutter packages get does not install new package

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to install a package (dynamic_theme) in flutter. When I run `flutter packages get -v` it does not even try to install the package.

So far I've tried:

- Running `flutter packages get`
- Running `flutter packages get`
- Restarting my computer
- Updated flutter
- Added another package but that did not install either
- Updated Android Studio

In my pubspec.yaml I've put:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core:
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  dynamic_theme: ^1.0.1 # the package does not install
  uuid: 2.0.0 # the package does not install
```

In the logs for the verbose run of `flutter packages get` where it installs the packages it outputs:

```
[ +422 ms] Running "flutter packages get" in quiz_app... (completed in 0.4s)
[  +57 ms] Found plugin firebase_core at E:\Other\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.3.4\
[  +13 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences at E:\Other\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.2\
[ +141 ms] Found plugin firebase_core at E:\Other\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.3.4\
[   +6 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences at E:\Other\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.2\
[  +26 ms] "flutter get" took 718ms.
```

I expected that flutter downloaded and installed the packages, but it does just check for updates on the already installed packages like [firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core).

Comment: Why don't you have a version for ```firebase_core```? Is that a copy-paste mistake or your actual pubspec.yaml file? I think that might be your problem (looking at your comments). The current version out there is ```0.3.4```.

Comment: I think that not specifying the version always gets the latest, but I can try changing it.

Comment: @tomerpacific Specifying the version did not help. It downloads 0.3.4 during both with and without the version.

Comment: @Alive - I have two things to suggest : either try starting a fresh new project and only add the desired library and see what happens. Or, have you tried running ```flutter clean```?

Comment: `flutter clean` did not change anything. Starting a new project did not install the package either. I tried installing the package UUID which I know works but that did not install either.

Comment: @Alive - without the dynamic theme package, do other packages install successfully?

Comment: @tomerpacific Removing the dynamic theme package from the dependencies did not allow other packages to be installed.

Comment: try surrounding double quotes "^1.0.1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something solved it randomly. I did not do anything but try multiple times. After some 10 attempts it downloaded and installed both uuid and dynamic_theme.

Answer (score 58):

Close and open your editor. Worked for me ;)

Comment: I was using my sanity over this. Unbelievable. Thanks

Answer (score 44):

so basically run:

```
flutter clean

flutter packages get

flutter packages upgrade
```

Restart Android Studio or Visual Studio

you can restart VSC by:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then a search bar will appear and then type: "restart" and smash the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 21):

hi I have a similar problem I deleted a package from the dart packages folder and when I run flutter pub run it won't download and work so I tried all the way people said but something worked for me is I tried to repairing pub cache and it worked
just run

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Comment: Thank you, reza47.  I had the same problem when I tried to re-install the same package after the removal, nothing worked till I tried your sugges

Comment: Only a restart worked for me. However, this has helped me with other similar issues!

Comment: for me it was that command then flutter clean then flutter pub get

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my issue with `geolocator`package when I build iOS version it fails but after I tried your command line now it works!

Answer (score 9):

I am currently experiencing this situation. When looking into it deeper, I've found that the packages never actually install themselves into the flutter packages folder.

The response I'm getting is exit `code 0`, with no error actual being reported.

When I put in my import `'package:english_words/english_words.dart';`
it just shows up as a problem.

Comment: I am sorry, but where is the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 7):

In Visual studio code, the thing that fixed it for me was

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and then search "Dart: restart analysis server", in the pop up bar.

after the analysis was finished it worked like a charm.

Comment: `F1` > `Restart Dart Analysis Server` in Android Studio worked too.

Comment: This is truly a Champ!! It works likeee! Thanks brrr.

Answer (score 6):

To install package you have to press double enter after the `dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
carousel_pro: ^1.0.0`

Then Package name e.g: carousel_pro: ^1.0.0. 
Enter,spaces, and back spaces matter in  pubspec.yaml File. I hope this resolve the issue.

Comment: it resolved my problem too, it is funy : )

Answer (score 4):

If you delete a package from External Libraries > Dart Packages, you need to run  -->
`flutter pub cache repair`
This will reinstall all the external libraries and update the missing ones. `Get dependencies` or `Pub get` and you are good to go!

Answer (score 3):

If anyone of you is using Android Studio then Going to File->Invalidate Caches/Restart is your friend.

This is what has helped me, getting the updated dependencies for Android Studio.

Comment: Restart worked even with VS Code, it's weird but it worked

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I had my project in my google drive folder which has a space in the path. I moved it to the android studio folder and then pub get worked fine

Comment: Not sure why the down vote. This worked for me, seems a bit unfair

Comment: Don't worry, I'm here to save the day with a +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add ^ to   uuid: 2.0.0
Good luck

```
  // The last version is 
uuid: ^2.0.1
```

Comment: I tried that, it did not change anything but now randomly like 10 attempts of just `flutter packages get -v` it downloaded both uuid and dynamic_theme.

Answer (score 1):

in pubspec.yaml click Pub get
it work for me

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IntelliJ or Android Studio, do the following:

- flutter clean
- flutter packages get

and then click on File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

After the IDE restarts chances are you may still face error but this time when you hover the code the import library tooltip will show

Answer (score 1):

If you moved your project files from to a newly created project (probably because of AndroidX migration), check that your new `pubspec.yaml` is the same as the previous one or your code will blow up with package errors.

Answer (score 1):

I hit `flutter pub get` .
Though it ended with exit code 0 , i couldnt access my dependency lib classes via intellicense.

I restarted Android studio with Invalidate & Restart. That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by accepting Android Licenses using `flutter doctor --android licenses`. Note that you must install android SDK command-line tools to make this command work.

Steps:

- Install command-line tools via SDK manager
- Accept android licenses
- Run flutter pub get

Answer (score 1):

> **in `pubspec.yml` be sure you add your packages under `dependencies` not `dev_dependencies`**

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Deleting .pub-cache folder
   [this directory is located under $HOME/.pub-cache (on macOS and Linux), or in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Pub\Cache (on Windows)](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/environment-variables#:%7E:text=Some%20of%20pub%27s%20dependencies%20are,depending%20on%20the%20Windows%20version)
2. flutter pub clean
3. flutter pub get

Answer (score 0):

Some quick fix for **Android Studio** :

> 1. Check proper space before package name ( **very much important** )

2. Click on **Pub get** or from terminal run  command `flutter packages get`
   , and you can download these dependencies, After successfully downloading the package, This warning is just here to reminds you that your dependencies aren't downloaded
   => Click on **`Get Dependencies`** of the first warning

If you still getting error then follow below steps:

3. **Clean App** : Android Studio > Tools > Flutter > Flutter Clean
4. **Restart Android Studio**

Answer (score 0):

After the update (23 September 2020) of Android Studio 4.1 the builtin terminal is not working for getting new packages.
Solution: Run the command prompt in Administrator mode. Go to your project directory and run command `flutter clean` after that run `flutter pub get`.

Answer (score 0):

in my case nothing has happened after flutter upgrade, clean, pub get, etc.
but when I restart my project it automatically gets pub Packages in VS code.

in a menu bar, Run => start debugging.